# How do I find the Sum of the following Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a Grade 12 Learner and I need help solving the sum of the sequence below:
$$T_1 = 1/2$$
$$T_2 = 1/3$$
$$T_3 = 1/4$$
$$T_4 = 1/5$$
and so on, up to $T_{98}$.

I figured out the general equation for the sequence, but can seem to figured out if it is arithmetic or geometric, so i can find the sum of it

The general equation I derived is $T_n= \frac{1}{n+1}$, but what would the $S_n$ equation be?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: There is no easy equation for $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dotsb+\frac1n$, but we have good ways to approximate it. (That sum is denoted by the symbol $H_n$.)

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I had a look at the Harmonic series, but couldn't really figure it out, i appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

The $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number is $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$$It is denoted by $H_n$. It seems your are looking for the value of $H_n-1$. We can [approximate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#/media/File:HarmonicNumbers.svg) $H_n$ as $\log(n)+\gamma$, where $\log$ is the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Your answer will therefore be given by
$$H_{98}-1\approx\log(98)+\gamma-1\approx 4.584967+0.577216-1\approx 4.16218$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n+1} = \psi(m+2) + \gamma - 1 $$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi(m+2)$ is the digamma function evaluated at $m+2$. For your problem, take $m=98$.